# How a vba code can remove carriage RETURN new line character from text file?

Tags: excel, vba

I can not see this rogue characters when I open the file through Notepad. But when i open it through Ultraedit it can be seen at the end of the line.

I have tried few things mentioned below but no luck.

```
Replace(MyRange, Chr(10), "")
Replace$(MyRange, vbCrLf, "")
```

Comment: Have you tried `Chr(13)`?  Or use `=CODE(MID(A1,4,1))` where character #4 is the line break - it will tell you the ANSI character at position 4.

Comment: Is that literally your code, or are you actually assigning the return value back to `MyRange`?

Comment: assigning the return value back to MyRange

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - Tried this as well but not working.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the character in UltraEdit? Is it the pilcrow? ¶

Comment: Did the `Code` suggestion return anything?

Comment: Either look at the file in a hex editor or cast it to a character array and figure out exactly what the character is. You have the code to remove it, so at this point the only way this question is answerable is to see the text file. Otherwise we're all just going to end up speculating what your mystery character is.

Comment: @oxwilder Yes the same character.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to trim off the last character?
e.g. something like =LEFT(TRIM(MyRange),LEN(TRIM(MyRange))-1) ?
(edit: added trim for good measure)